# What is the method to reset the Planar 1910m monitor?

Tags: display, reset

My monitor (a Planar, apparently model number PL1910M) is not working. (It is flashing a green / orange sequence which I believe to be an error code. The sequence, in case it helps consists of orange and green three times quickly followed by a longer orange, then another green followed by a long period where both colors appear to be present).

I vaguely recall a co-worker suffering from a similar problem, and our IT department "resetting" the monitor by holding down a certain set of keys as they apply power. Unfortunately, I do not remember what that key sequence was, our IT department is not responding, and the Planar web site is blocked by the content filtering firewall we have in place!

What is the sequence to perform the reset? (For bonus geek-credit, what does the code mean... as if it indicates a blown component clearly a reset will not help me. ;-))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [information found here](http://marsbox.com/blog/howtos/planar-pl-lcd-monitor-fix/),

- If your serial number starts with A (the power button is the last on the right)
  Unplug the power cable and, while holding down the second and third buttons (counting from the left), plug in the power cable. Release the buttons either immediately, after five seconds or after the light turns green (apparently whichever works)
- If your serial number starts with B (the power button is in the middle)
  Follow the same procedure, except use the second and fourth buttons

Comment: I had to disconnect the display cable before I did this. It worked. The way you can tell that it's working is that it pops up the 'No signal' box. Thanks!

Comment: A coworker just had to do it again in our office. For the model with the power button in the middle we waited five seconds after plugging in and immediately released the buttons. (You'll also see the flashing behavior change right around 5 seconds.)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  I wasn't even seeing a "no signal" message and I couldn't turn it off using the power button.

One of the keys is to let go of the button as soon as the power light comes on and goes green.

Apparently it means the monitor failed to synchronize.  I found that out from [this site](http://www.etcconnect.com/Community/wikis/products/knowledgebase-planar-lcd-monitors-pl1700-1700m-1711m-1910m-1911m-with-eos-ion-element.aspx).

Also, the link to the planar manual is [here](http://www.planar.com/products/docs/cbu/current_manual/mn-planar-pl1910m.pdf).

Answer (score -2):

There you go.......check this Link it has the answer to your problem..

https://www.etcconnect.com/uploadedFiles/Main_Site/Content/Support/Articles/Consoles/Eos/Planar%20PL%20line%20LCD%20Monitor%20Problem%20and%20Solutions.pdf

Comment: While the link might provide the answer to the problem, links can get outdated and break. Please provide an answer to the solution in the post.

Comment: Please include a relevant quote from that link ...